# Does Android annotation inheritance is possible?

Tags: android, android-annotations

Let's say we have the following interfaces -

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({EventA.EVENT})
    public @interface EventA{
        String EVENT= "eventA";
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({EventB.EVENT})
    public @interface EventB{
        String EVENT= "eventB";
    }
```

I want to declare a function in which his argument type is one of thus interfaces such as -

```
public void foo(Event x) { // Event should be only EventA or EventB
  ...
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Not unless there's a common base class.  Or if you want to use Generics.  Although passing an instance of an Annotation is kind of rare, is that really what you wanted?

Comment: I want to restrict the values the function receive (actually a specific String values ) and as I understand it can be Enum or with annotation

Comment: An enum can definitely do that.  An annotation is not a standard way of doing that.  And you wouldn't do it by passing annotation objects around.  The only time annotation objects are used is in reflection based code.  And mostly that's done at compile time for code generation.